# Windows Server AppFabric Caching Session Storage

Tags: windows, session, caching, appfabric

Can Windows Server AppFabric Caching share one session between 2 or more different Web Applications? How can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this. You need to configure your session provider to use the caching service (they have a provider specifically for this). Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790859.aspx

Answer (score 2):

With AppFabric 1.1, a new provider is available.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790859(v=azure.10).aspx
For sharing sessions between different websites/apps, be sure to specify the same shareid/cachename in config.